# Absolute import in package of unknown name

Tags: python, import, package

I am writing a package to be shared by various projects. I have import statements in my package such as:

`from my_package.module.script import foo`

However if I place this package in my project under any name other than `my_project` then the code will break. Is there a way around this **without** relying on relative imports since relative imports get really messy to write?

Comment: Two options: relative imports, don't change the package's name.

Answer (score 0):

Since your package is shared by multiple projects, you may consider installing this package into your Python environment. To achieve this, you can create a file named `setup.py` in the same directory as my_project and the content looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='my_package',
        version='0.0.1',
        description='Short description for your package.',
        long_description='Long description for your package.',
        long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
        author='Your name',
        author_email='Your email',
        packages=find_packages(),
        include_package_data=True,
    )
```

Then run `python setup.py install` to install this package. After doing this, all of your import statements like `from my_package.module.script import foo` are no longer relative imports, thus avoiding the problem.